# How to fix string interpolation is not working in textarea with fornControlName?(Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-material, textarea, string-interpolation

in the following code if I use

> formControlName="work_sample_description"

for textarea , the text area does not load with the value of

> WorkSampleObj.work_sample_description

if I remove

> formControlName="work_sample_description"

code runs as expected..!

How to fix it?

```
<form [formGroup]="workSampleEditForm" (ngSubmit)="edit_work_sample(workSampleEditForm.value)">
        <mat-card-content>
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="full-width">
              <textarea matInput rows="7" formControlName="work_sample_description">{{WorkSampleObj.work_sample_description}}</textarea>
          </mat-form-field>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-button *ngIf="workSampleEditForm.disabled" (click)="workSampleEditForm.enable()">Edit description</button>
          <button mat-button *ngIf="workSampleEditForm.enabled">Save Changes</button>
          <button mat-button>Delete</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
   </form>
```

I tried also this

```
workSampleEditForm = new FormGroup({
    work_sample_description : new FormControl(this.WorkSampleObj.work_sample_description,[])
  });

---------------
<textarea matInput rows="7" [formControlName]="'work_sample_description'"></textarea>
```

Comment: The question is, how do you get the value of `this.WorkSampleObj.work_sample_description`? See my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, that `[formControlName]` expects string name of the given form control. And you are passing reference to it. If you form group `workSampleEditForm` contains `work_sample_description` form control then just pass its name as a string (put the name in the single quotes)

```html
<textarea 
  matInput rows="7" 
  [formControlName]="'work_sample_description'">
</textarea>
```

As mentioned by @MikeOne, if you get the value of `this.WorkSampleObj.work_sample_description` from API and not when the Form is created, you should set it using `setValue`.

```typescript
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.someApiCall.subscribe((res) => {
    this.testForm.get('textAreaFC').setValue(res.value);
  });
}
```

See **updated** [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k326sd?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Not work in my case..!

Comment: ```this.workSampleEditForm.get('work_sample_description').setValue(this.WorkSampleObj.work_sample_description);``` How fix object is possibly null error here..?

Comment: Simplest solution is to add a question mark: `setValue(this.WorkSampleObj?.work...)`

Answer (score 0):

[(ngModel)] solve my issue.

```
<textarea matInput rows="7" formControlName="work_sample_description" 
[(ngModel)]="WorkSampleObj.work_sample_description"></textarea>
```

Comment: Not good practice to combine ngModel with formControl though.. ?

Comment: So what should i do..?

Comment: My guess is that work_sample_description" is loaded async after you’ve setup the form. If so, you use setValue(value) on your formControl to set it.

Comment: ```ngOnInit(): void { this.workSampleEditForm.get('work_sample_description')?.setValue(this.WorkSampleObj.work_sample_description); 
  }``` It works,,,! Thanks...!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).